# SAPUI5 -Problems rendering Content with _each loop

Tags: sapui5

I have a panel (Categories) which contains child "questions" (input boxes).

The Panels are displaying fine, but each Panels content: property can include more the one question.

```
var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel({
            expandable: true,
            expanded: false,
            headerText: oData.results[0].CategoryDesc,
            id: "Panel" + index,
            content: _.each(oViewData.categories, function(result, index2) {
                new sap.m.Input("iCategory" + index + index2, {             
            });
        })
    });
    oPanel.placeAt("panelContent");
```

I'm retrieving the data fine, but the content won't render. I'm getting the error message:

```
The renderer for class sap.ui.core.Control is not defined or does not define a render function! Rendering of __control0 will be skipped! -
```

Is it possible to use _each (underscoreJs) in the content property? If not, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

you can push your data to an array and use it in the content area:

```
var oPanelContent = [];

_.each(oViewData.categories, function(result, index2) {
    oPanelContent.push(new sap.m.Input("iCategory" + index + index2, {             
    })
);


var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel({
            expandable: true,
            expanded: false,
            headerText: oData.results[0].CategoryDesc,
            id: "Panel" + index,
            content: oPanelContent
        })
    });
    oPanel.placeAt("panelContent");
```

Comment: Solved with addContent :)